# Find mean and variance of $Y=\langle X-\xi,n \rangle$

Tags: vector-spaces, normal-distribution, variance

I have the following homework and having difficulties approaching this:

Let X be a regular normal distribution on a vector space V med center $\xi$ and precision $\langle .,. \rangle$ and let $\eta \neq 0$ be a vector in V

Show that the real random variable $Y=\langle X-\xi,\eta \rangle$ has variance $||\eta||^2$

Any hint/help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe something like $\cdots=\mathsf{Var}(\sum_i(X_i-\xi_i)\eta_i)=\mathsf{Var}(X_i\eta_i)=\sum_i\eta_i^2\mathsf{Var}X_i=\sum_i\eta_i^2$? Are the $X_i$ independent with $\mathsf{Var}(X_i)=1$? I am just guessing because I am not familiar with a part of the terminology used in your question.

Comment: @drhab No, it is not stated that they are independent nor is the variance stated